# Identifying continuously-recording seismic stations

Tags: geophysics, seismology, data-analysis

I am trying to identify which stations within the NCEDC network are continuously recording ground motion, and which record only intermittently. I am using `obspy`'s FDSN client to access station metadata and waveforms. Is there a way to do this without accessing the waveform data?

For example, the station [NC.J032](https://ds.iris.edu/mda/NC/J032/?starttime=2009-11-25&endtime=3000-01-01) appears to record intermittently, as there was only 1 trace lasting about 3 minutes between 2023-01-01 and 2023-01-31. Is there some way I can figure this out using station metadata only, either using `obspy` or through some other means?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use WILBER3 by IRIS to find out more I'm not sure if that is what you need but give it a try. Also, have you tried retrieving the event data which got recorded by that station for whatever period of time the station is operating using Obspy get_events?

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to download long time series from specific stations (for example, data for a whole month), so I'm trying to identify stations that actually have that kind of data, as opposed to just event data. I don't think your proposed solution helps me with that goal.